.DWG files don't show up in target package selection window to import
When trying to import .dwg files from an engineer into a new QGIS project, no files appear in the file folder when I am selecting the target package. I've tried with several files with the same result.
Would the fact that the files are purged impact their visibility?
Is there something I am missing?

QGIS can import both DXF and DWG files. Please read the QGIS Desktop User Guide at https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-dxf-or-dwg-file

Does QGIS have an own DXF/DGW provider, or is is using GDAL https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/vector/dwg.html?

QGIS uses GDAL/OGR when importing a DWG file via drag&drop or Data Source Manager ► Vector, while it uses an internal importer based on the libdxfrw library when importing a DWG file via Project ► Import/Export ► Import Layers from DWG/DXF.

Problem was that it was an AutoCAD .DWG. Had the client export to .dxf and it is working now.

Sometimes it's the type of objects in DWG-files that causes these kind of problems.  Modern dwg-files can contain more types of objects than older dxf-files.  So saving to dxf can solve that problem.  If in a future AutoCAD import saving as dxf doesn't help, you can also try to explode objects in your drawing before saving it as dwg or dxf.
